# XML in markup, any ideas why?

Tags: xhtml, tags, markup

I am doing some research on a Motorola site and came across a ton of weird markup. I wanted to get ideas on why this is used and/or why it is a good idea?

Using [this page](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Enterprise+Mobility) as an example, you can view the source and see tons of tags like

```
<title xml:lang="en" lang="en" 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head xml:lang="en">
```

Any ideas? How does this affect SEO and and general best practices? How good or bad is this?

The page seems to explode when I run it through the W3C validator.

Comment: They are probably just following these practices: http://enterprise-html.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are, the page is being built from a number of fragments and processes that don't attempt to maintain valid HTML. With a mixture of knowledge, luck and testing it's possible to build web pages that work fine, even though they're nowhere near valid.

How does it affect SEO? Probably surprisingly little. Search engine parsers have to do the same thing that browsers do, otherwise authors would exploit differences to serve one content to browsers and different content to search engines.

The success of a search engine depends on matching the search string to pages that the display the content that the user was looking for. So long as the page displays correctly, whether the page uses valid markup or not is of no interest to the user, and therefore of no interest to the search engine.

In terms of general best practices, it scores 0.

Answer (score 0):

The web page is just a normal [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/normative.html) which leverages [XML internationalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/). I don't think SEO is a goal here.